# Как составить регулярное выражения для замены вк "тегов" на ссылки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, вконтакте

Получаю текст постов из вк и там могут быть ссылки на какие-то паблики или людей, их нужно заменить на ссылки. Примеры:
[id1|Паша][durov|Паша][club1231|Test][club1231222|Тестовая страница] и тд. Их нужно заменить на (пример)

```
<a href="https://vk.com/durov">Паша</a>
```

Прочитал, что и как в регулярках, погуглил, но все равно не получается... Составил с помощью какого-то сервиса регулярку, она не подошла, потом полазил в js от вк, нашел там регулярку, но ее нужно изменить, а это для меня сложновато...

```
(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)((\\(*)("+i.join("|")+"))(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужен php

```
<?php
    $re = '/\[(.+)\|(.+)\]/U';
    $str = '[id1|Паша] Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм [durov|Паша] деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. С другой стороны консультация с широким активом [club1231|Test] позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке направлений прогрессивного развития. Таким образом начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции способствует подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений [club1231222|Тестовая страница] развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же укрепление и развитие структуры требуют от нас анализа системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.';
    $subst = '<a href="https://vk.com/$1">$2</a>';
    echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
?>
```

Demo
https://regex101.com/r/x9Y4oE/1

Comment: Благодарю, все отлично работает)